# proxy/mock object in c# for wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy, mocking

I am trying to create a generic way of using either a mock object or the proxy object when calling the GetGreeting(). How can i structure the code so it is more generic ie not only for the GreetingService? I have to somehow pass in the typeof WCF service i guess?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace proxymockproblem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GreetingServiceManager caller = new GreetingServiceManager(false);
            Console.Write(caller.GetCaller().GetGreeting());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public interface IGreetingServiceManager
    {
        string GetGreeting();
    }

    public class proxyGreetingService : IGreetingServiceManager
    {
        public string GetGreeting()
        { return "hi from proxyGreetingService"; }
    }

    public class mockGreetingService : IGreetingServiceManager
    {
        public string GetGreeting()
        { return "hi from mock"; }
    }


    public class GreetingServiceManager
    {
        bool UseMock;
        public GreetingServiceManager(bool usemock)
        {
            UseMock = usemock;
        }

        public IGreetingServiceManager GetCaller()
        {
            if (UseMock)
            {
                return new proxyGreetingService();
            }
            else
            {
                return new mockGreetingService();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look a the [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) class

If you want a proxy for wcf specifically that should do the trick

for doing tests you can use one of the mocking frameworks outthere such as [moles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963.aspx), [nmock](http://www.nmock.org/) or [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)

Comment: i am not looking for a mocking framework, just for a way of structuring my code in a more generic way. The code i attached is specifically for 1 method ie GreetingService. I want to create a class that , when instantiated will call either the mock class or the proxy class. Maybe by using delegates or anonymous types?

Comment: right, but using the ChannelFactory<T> you can make the wcf implementation at runtime, so you'd make your GreetingServiceManager into a ServiceManager<T> and then use the T with ChannelFactory to connect to wcf and with you mocking framework of choice for the mocking bit